# How to remove CORS restriction for one Controller Action in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, cors, .net-core-3.1

How to remove CORS restriction for one Controller Action

I have implemented CORS for one of my application for all controllers/ all action at one place.
But don't know how to remove this restriction for just single controller

My code for one other place is

```
public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).
            ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
            {
            }).UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<StartupShutdownHandler>();
        private const string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        public StartupShutdownHandler(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }        
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            CorsRelatedPolicyAddition(services);
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            });        }

        private void CorsRelatedPolicyAddition(IServiceCollection services)
        {

                services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder => { builder.AllowedAnyOrigins().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); });
                });

        }        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {...


            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

            ..

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For entire controller (all the method in it)

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://www.example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
 public class TestController : ApiController
 {
    // Controller methods not shown...
 }
```

For a particular method only

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://www.example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetItem(int id) { ... }
```

For more detail see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: I am not restricting origin. May be you mean EnableCors on action. do i need to add any thing in startup as well or no?